# How to optimize the 64 if else if statement in php

Tags: php

Can i optimize code to small one because i have 2 selects and 8 options

This is php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['groupM']) && isset($_POST['groupF'])) {
        $groupM = $_POST['groupM'];
        $groupF = $_POST['groupF'];
        if ($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 1) {
            echo "It's a girl";
        }elseif($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 2){
            echo "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results.";
        }elseif($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 3){
            echo "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results.";
        }elseif($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 4){
            echo "It's a boy";
        }elseif($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 5){
            echo "It's a girl";
        }elseif($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 6){
            echo "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results.";
        }elseif($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 7){
            echo "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results.";
        }elseif($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 7){
            echo "It's a boy";
        }
        // ... and so on. 64 result have
    }
```

This code calculate baby's gender prediction by the blood type (boy or girl) choosing Father blood type and mother blood type and showing result

This is html code:

```
<form id="get_my_baby_gender" method="POST">
            <label for="groupM">Father's blood group:</label>
                <select class="input_box" id="groupM" name="groupM" size="1">
                    <option value="1">O(I) Rh−</option>
                    <option value="2">O(I) Rh+</option>
                    <option value="3">A(II) Rh−</option>
                    <option value="4">A(II) Rh+</option>
                    <option value="5">B(III) Rh−</option>
                    <option value="6">B(III) Rh+</option>
                    <option value="7">AB(IV) Rh−</option>
                    <option value="8">AB(IV) Rh+</option>
                </select>

            <label for="groupF">Mother's blood group:</label>
            <select class="input_box" id="groupF" name="groupF" size="1">
                <option value="1">O(I) Rh−</option>
                <option value="2">O(I) Rh+</option>
                <option value="3">A(II) Rh−</option>
                <option value="4">A(II) Rh+</option>
                <option value="5">B(III) Rh−</option>
                <option value="6">B(III) Rh+</option>
                <option value="7">AB(IV) Rh−</option>
                <option value="8">AB(IV) Rh+</option>
            </select>

            <input name="method" type="hidden" value="blood_group">
            <input id="get_gender_results" type="submit" value="What's my baby's gender?">
        </form>
```

Comment: `switch ($groupM*10 + $groupF)` and then `case 11:` till `case 77:`, or even an array map would be simpler.

Comment: For people not having any clue about biologics, what is *"... and so on. 64 result have"*? Or what is the biological rule?

Comment: Did you use the same tables as https://whatsmybabygender.com/parents-blood-types ? According to this tables, your code e.g. at `if($groupM == 1 && $groupF == 5){ echo "It's a girl"; }` does not work correctly, it should be unpredictable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up a two dimensional array on `$groupM` and `$groupF` and use their values as indexes into it. In this case I've assigned values of `-1`, `0` and `1` to represent the 3 possible outcomes (girl, unknown and boy):

```
$gender = array(1 => array(1 => 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, -1),
                2 => array(1 => 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0),
                ...
                8 => array(1 => 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0)
                );
if (isset($_POST['groupM']) && isset($_POST['groupF'])) {
    $groupM = $_POST['groupM'];
    $groupF = $_POST['groupF'];
    $result = $gender[$groupM][$groupF];
    switch ($result) {
        case 1:
            echo "It's a girl!";
            break;
        case 0:
            echo "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results.";
            break;
        case -1:
            echo "It's a boy";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you help me this code convert javascript code?

Comment: @user3406957 you should ask a new question as you will get a better result from people who are experts in JavaScript. You can link back to this question for context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function, according to your example, to check if gender is not predictable, you can try something like that:

```
if($groupM == 1 && in_array($groupF, [2, 3, 6, 7])){
    echo "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn it into a function to make it easier to handle:

```
echo returnGender( $_POST['groupM'] , $_POST['groupF'] );

function returnGender( $father , $mother ){
    // Boy Possibilities 
    $boy = [
        [1, 4], [1, 7]
    ];
    // Girl Possibilities 
    $girl = [
        [1, 1], [1, 5]
    ];
    if( in_array( [ $father , $mother ], $boy ) || in_array( [ $mother , $father], $boy ) ){
        return "It's A Boy";
    }
    if( in_array( [ $father , $mother ], $girl )|| in_array( [ $mother , $father], $girl ) ){
        return "It's A Girl";
    }
    return "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results."; 
}
```

Comment: Very nice and more helpful Thanks so much. I have two questions
1) Page open and return "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results." this text on the page, how to hidden it after choosing show this text

Comment: You only run `echo returnGender( $_POST['groupM'] , $_POST['groupF'] );` whe nthe form has been submitted. `if (isset($_POST['groupM']) && isset($_POST['groupF'])) { echo returnGender( $_POST['groupM'] , $_POST['groupF'] ); }`

Comment: 2) [1, 4], [1, 8], [2, 3], [2, 7], [3, 2], [3, 6], [4, 1], [4, 5], after this array repeated number but reversed [5, 4], [5, 6], [5, 8], [6, 3], [6, 5], [6, 7], [7, 2], [7, 6], [7, 8], [8, 1], [8, 5], [8, 7] can i solve it?

Comment: What seems to be the issue? You don't want to add them all?

Comment: I must be type all numbers? for example [1,4] and [4,1] it is a same result

Comment: My edit should fix that. If mother is 1 and father is 4 OR if father is 4 and mother is 1

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve it mathematically in a bitwise logical way.

Assuming you are using the method of https://whatsmybabygender.com/parents-blood-types, we have the following tables:

[image]
[image]

We can see, a different Rhesus factor predicts a boy, equal ones a girl. The blood type schema is similar. If both types are even or odd, a girl is predicted, if even/odd is different, a boy is predicted. There's an exception when at least one of the blood groups is III or IV then always a boy is predicted by the blood types.

As usual in informatics, we use a zero-based enumeration of 0-3 for the blood groups I-IV. This way we use the binary numbers 00, 01, 10, 11, i.e. 2 bits. If the lower bit is set, the id number is odd (i.e. even type I-IV). If the second bit is set, we have one of the types III or IV.

The third bit (value 4) we will use to indicate the "Rhesus factor +".

We could generate `<option>` tags preserving the last selected option like that:

```
function blood_options($sel)
{
  foreach(['O(I)', 'A(II)', 'B(III)', 'AB(IV]'] as $k => $v)
  {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $k  ;?>"<?php if($sel === $k  ) echo ' selected';?>><?php echo $v, ' Rh-'?></option>;
    <option value="<?php echo $k|4;?>"<?php if($sel === $k+4) echo ' selected';?>><?php echo $v, ' Rh+'?></option>;
<?php
  }
}
```

A bitwise XOR operation, `^` operator in PHP, indicates differences on each bit of two operands. We can use this to check bit 3 (value 4, our Rhesus factor bit) and bit 0 (value 1, even/odd number).

```
$m   = intval($_POST['groupM']); // get the numeric value
$f   = intval($_POST['groupF']); // get the numeric value
$xor = $m ^ $f;                  // indicate bitwise differences
```

Now we can find out, which genders are predicted by blood types and Rhesus factors:

```
$type1 = 1 & $xor          ;   // last bit of (m xor f) => even/odd group different
$type2 = 1 & (($m | $f)>>1);   // at least one of the second bits set => there is a group 2 (III) or 3 (IV)

$type  = $type1 | $type2    ;   // => 1 if at least one of type1 or type2 indicates maskulinum
$rhf   = 1&($xor>>2)        ;   // different rhesus? => 1 indicates maskulinum

$result = $type + $rhf    ;   // sum results in 0: 2x femininum ; 1: 1x m + 1x f ; 2: 2x maskulinum
var_dump($type1, $type2, $type,
```

In the code above, we have also moved the significant bit to position 0 (value 1) using the *SHIFT LEFT* operator `>>` and masked out all other bits by the *AND* operation `1 &`.

After calculating the sum as `$result`, we have

- 0 = 2 predictions: girl
- 1 = different predictions
- 2 = 2 predictions: boy

#### Putting it all together and written in short expressions, it finally looks like that:

```
if(isset($_POST['groupM'], $_POST['groupF']))
{
  $m   = intval($_POST['groupM']);
  $f   = intval($_POST['groupF']);
  $xor = $m ^ $f;

  echo
  [
    "It's a girl",
    "Baby's gender can not be predicted — Rh factor and blood type produce different results.",
    "It's a boy"
  ][(1 & ((($m | $f)>>1) | $xor)) + (1&($xor>>2))];
}
```

#### The HTML generation:

```
function blood_options($sel)
{
  foreach(['O(I)', 'A(II)', 'B(III)', 'AB(IV]'] as $k => $v)
  {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $k  ;?>"<?php if($sel === $k  ) echo ' selected';?>><?php echo $v, ' Rh-'?></option>;
    <option value="<?php echo $k+4;?>"<?php if($sel === $k|4) echo ' selected';?>><?php echo $v, ' Rh+'?></option>;
<?php
  }
}
?>

<form id="get_my_baby_gender" method="POST">
  <label for="groupM">Father's blood group:</label>
  <select class="input_box" id="groupM" name="groupM" size="1">
<?php blood_options($m); ?>
  </select>

  <label for="groupF">Mother's blood group:</label>
  <select class="input_box" id="groupF" name="groupF" size="1">
<?php blood_options($f); ?>
  </select>

  <input name="method" type="hidden" value="blood_group">
  <input id="get_gender_results" type="submit" value="What's my baby's gender?">
</form>
```